# Alert async in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, async-await

```
 public async Task<IViewComponentResult> Invokeasync()
 {
   return View("/Views/Product/ShowProduct.cshtml");
 }
```

[image]

In the ProductGroupComponent part, I don't know why it gives an async error and doesn't let me build the project, and in previous versions of .NET, like .NET 5, it didn't have this problem and it was built without errors.
In the ProductGroupComponent part, I don't know why it gives an async error and doesn't let me build the project, and in previous versions of .NET, like .NET 5, it didn't have this problem and it was built without errors.

Comment: As far as I can see it's not an error, it's a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mark a method as `async`, you need to use `await` at least once for the warning to disappear. In this simple method, you do not have any async code that you could await. Hence, the easiest way is to make this a *synchronous* method, e.g.:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
  return View("/Views/Product/ShowProduct.cshtml");
}
```